# Pass function reference to function fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I'm currently playing around with `coffeescript` and websockets using `nodejs`.
I created a `class SocketHandler` for managing websocket clients:

```
class SocketHandler
    constructor: (@server) ->
        @server.on "connection", @onClientConnect   

    onClientConnect: (socket) ->
        console.log "client connected"
        socket.on "close", @onClientDisconnect

    onClientDisconnect: (code, message) ->
        console.log "client disconnected"

ws = require "ws"
server = ws.Server { port: 8080 }
sockethandler = new SocketHandler server
```

When I run the script and a client connects I get the following error message:

```
client connected
events.js:210
    throw new TypeError('listener must be a function');
    ^

TypeError: listener must be a function
[...]
```

I have no clue why this happens. In my view I'm passing a function reference to `socket.on` as the second parameter.

I tried to investigate further and tried to output `onClientDisconnect` to see what type it has.
So I changed

```
onClientConnect: (socket) ->
    console.log "client connected"
    socket.on "close", @onClientDisconnect
```

to

```
onClientConnect: (socket) ->
    console.log "client connected"
    console.log @onClientDisconnect
    socket.on "close", @onClientDisconnect
```

resulting in getting an `undefined` value as output.

Now I'm really confused and I think I'm missing something fundamental at how the language works.
Can anyone of you help me out?

Comment: Is that your real indentation? Shouldn't `onClientConnect` and `onClientDisconnect` be indented a level so that they're part of `SocketHandler`?

Comment: @muistooshort: oh missed that. thanks for the hint, corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reminder: `@onClientConnect` is shorthand for `this.onClientConnect`. `this` is exactly the problem here. The context of a function call (what `this` is inside a function) is determined at call time in Javascript. When you pass a function, the receiver receives it "without context", and when invoked as such, `this` won't refer to the `this` you're thinking/want/expect.

Long story short: you need to bind `this` to your function, so the `@` in `@onClientDisconnect` actually refers to your class instance:

```
@server.on "connection", @onClientConnect.bind @
```

Alternative in CoffeeScript (using a context-bound fat arrow callback):

```
@server.on "connection", => @onClientConnect()
```

Also see [How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/476)